# How to show different text in a div using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, show-hide

So I have a page that has 5 different photos. When you click on each photo, the div below will show accompanying text and then once you click the photo again, the text will hide. I am just a beginner with javascript, but what I want to implement is that different text will display based on the photo the user clicks on.

Right now when you click on a photo, the text will show. But when you click on another photo, the new text will show right underneath. What I'm asking is, how do you alter the jquery code so that text will show when you click on a photo, but when you're clicking on another photo, that old text will hide and new text will show. I am using all of Bootstrap's jQuery 'Collapse' functionality.

Thanks in advance!

I have a bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/sabby_fields/h7iP24nwST

Also, if possible, how would I show which photo the text accompanies? Like which photo is active? Like a simple text color change.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="team-bio">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" style="margin-bottom:10px;" contenteditable="false">
                 <h4 class="">Name 1</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" class="collapsed">
                <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                 <h4 class="">Name 2</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
             <h4 class="">Name 3</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
             <h4 class="">Name 4</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
             <h4 class="">Name 5</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="col-md-12 panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <!-- div to hide-->
        <p class="">This is for Person 1.</p>
    </div>
    <!--div to hide-->
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse col-md-12">
        <!-- div to hide-->
        <p class="">This is for Person 2.</p>
    </div>
    <!--div to hide-->
</div>
```

Bootstrap's jQuery Collapse feature:

```
var Collapse = function (element, options) {
this.$element      = $(element)
this.options       = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, options)
this.$trigger      = $(this.options.trigger).filter('[href="#' + element.id + '"], [data-target="#' + element.id + '"]')
this.transitioning = null

if (this.options.parent) {
  this.$parent = this.getParent()
} else {
  this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(this.$element, this.$trigger)
}

if (this.options.toggle) this.toggle()
}

Collapse.VERSION  = '3.3.0'

Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION = 350

Collapse.DEFAULTS = {
toggle: true,
trigger: '[data-toggle="collapse"]'
}

Collapse.prototype.dimension = function () {
var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
}

Collapse.prototype.show = function () {
if (this.transitioning || this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

var activesData
var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .panel').children('.in, .collapsing')

if (actives && actives.length) {
  activesData = actives.data('bs.collapse')
  if (activesData && activesData.transitioning) return
}

var startEvent = $.Event('show.bs.collapse')
this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

if (actives && actives.length) {
  Plugin.call(actives, 'hide')
  activesData || actives.data('bs.collapse', null)
}

var dimension = this.dimension()

this.$element
  .removeClass('collapse')
  .addClass('collapsing')[dimension](0)
  .attr('aria-expanded', true)

this.$trigger
  .removeClass('collapsed')
  .attr('aria-expanded', true)

this.transitioning = 1

var complete = function () {
  this.$element
    .removeClass('collapsing')
    .addClass('collapse in')[dimension]('')
  this.transitioning = 0
  this.$element
    .trigger('shown.bs.collapse')
}

if (!$.support.transition) return complete.call(this)

var scrollSize = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))

this.$element
  .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(complete, this))
  .emulateTransitionEnd(Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION)[dimension](this.$element[0][scrollSize])
}

Collapse.prototype.hide = function () {
if (this.transitioning || !this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

var startEvent = $.Event('hide.bs.collapse')
this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

var dimension = this.dimension()

this.$element[dimension](this.$element[dimension]())[0].offsetHeight

this.$element
  .addClass('collapsing')
  .removeClass('collapse in')
  .attr('aria-expanded', false)

this.$trigger
  .addClass('collapsed')
  .attr('aria-expanded', false)

this.transitioning = 1

var complete = function () {
  this.transitioning = 0
  this.$element
    .removeClass('collapsing')
    .addClass('collapse')
    .trigger('hidden.bs.collapse')
}

if (!$.support.transition) return complete.call(this)

this.$element
  [dimension](0)
  .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(complete, this))
  .emulateTransitionEnd(Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION)
}

Collapse.prototype.toggle = function () {
this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
}

Collapse.prototype.getParent = function () {
return $(this.options.parent)
  .find('[data-toggle="collapse"][data-parent="' + this.options.parent + '"]')
  .each($.proxy(function (i, element) {
    var $element = $(element)
    this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(getTargetFromTrigger($element), $element)
  }, this))
  .end()
}

Collapse.prototype.addAriaAndCollapsedClass = function ($element, $trigger) {
var isOpen = $element.hasClass('in')

$element.attr('aria-expanded', isOpen)
$trigger
  .toggleClass('collapsed', !isOpen)
  .attr('aria-expanded', isOpen)
}

function getTargetFromTrigger($trigger) {
var href
var target = $trigger.attr('data-target')
  || (href = $trigger.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') // strip for ie7

return $(target)
}
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question, too. From the Help Center: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on sqlfiddle.com or jsbin.com) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the bootstrap accordion to work properly, the collapsible elements need to be housed in panels. You will then need to override any of the panel styling you do not want.

In order to highlight which image was selected, you can add the "collapsed" class to the elements which toggle the collapse. Afterwards you apply some CSS rules that format these elements based on the presence of this class. Whenever an item is clicked, bootstrap removes the collapsed class from that element and adds it to the others in the panel-group.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" role="tab" class="collapsed">
      <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" contenteditable="false">
      <h4 class="">Name 1</h4>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo" role="tab" class="collapsed">
      <img class="img-responsive img-team-bio" src="http://placehold.it/150" contenteditable="false">
      <h4 class="">Name 2</h4>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 panel">
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <h4 class="">This is for person 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 panel">
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <h4 class="">This is for person 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#accordion .panel { box-shadow:none; border:none; margin:0; }
#accordion a { color:red; }
#accordion a.collapsed { color:#000; }
```

Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/2Sq6MHGkJx

Comment: thanks this worked but what if I had another section (another panel) right below it? Like for example someone clicked on the top row, the div showed, and then they clicked on the bottom row and then that older div disappeared and then the bottom div appeared for the bottom section.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you be a little more specific? For example: 'what if I had another section (another panel) right below it?' - What is 'it'? Perhaps, use the element IDs or classes.

Comment: sorry about that. I just actually placed my two sections in one panel so that the two sections would work in showing and hiding content. Thank you!